# Java Extends tag giving "symbol not found" error

Tags: java, extend, symbols

I currently have a Java program with a functioning Java class. I've created instances of that class manipulated them and printed them without any issues, however when I try to extend the class from the main method I get a symbol not found error.

```
public class Project3 extends StringInstrument{
```

The main class is Project3.java and the other class is StringInstrument.java so I'm not sure why netbeans knows where the StringInstrument.java file is to create and manipulate instances within it, but it cant find it to 'extend' it?

Comment: It looks fine - the problem is not in the code you show.

Comment: have tried you importing `StringInstrument` class?

Comment: Java jas strict requirements on files location. Each file should be located in the directory which name is corresponding with file's package directive. To find class, Java needs file be either in the same package (directory) or located with the help of `import` directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you need to find the package where StringInstrument.java is. 
And import it.

```
import stringInstrumentPackage.StringInstrument;
```

Comment: They're both inside the same package. Would I need to import it if they're both in it? Its package: project3  inside that you have Project3 with main class and StringInstrument

Comment: GAH! My code is crazy complicated so to avoid it I was going to write a smaller version and in doing so found my problem. The file name is StringInstrument.java but the CLASS I was trying to extend on WITHIN that file is Class Violin()

Comment: @leigero: Do you have the package declarations same in both the classes?

Comment: @leigero So Violin is a nested class of StringInstrument?

Comment: yes, the StringInstrument.java file was going to have several classes, but it only has the one Violin class. I was trying to 'extend' the entire StringInstrument file i guess rather than the Violin class within it

Comment: Mmn, don't think that should make a difference. But the best would be to separate the instruments in their own .java file. And you can have them in an instruments package if you like.